# Discontinuous Linear Functional on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

What's a classical (or most typical/famous) example of a Discontinuous Linear Functional on $(\mathcal{C}([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_1)$? And with an easy proof that it is in fact discontinuous.

Comment: What do you understand by $\|f\|_1$? Is it the $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$ or $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)| + \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f'(x)|$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$, $\forall f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

Point evaluation is probably the easiest, e.g., $Lf = f(0)$.